# Enter-PSSession returns PSInvalidOperationException

Tags: linux, powershell, ubuntu

i am trying to use:

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 10.10.10.5 -Credential administrator
```

And this gives me:

```
Enter-PSSession : MI_RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED
At line:1 char:1
+ Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 10.10.10.5 -Credential administrator ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (10.10.10.5:String) [Enter-PSSession], PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateRemoteRunspaceFailed
```

Ansible works without problem at the same time:

```
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible/modules/windows/setup.ps1
<10.10.10.5> ESTABLISH WINRM CONNECTION FOR USER: Administrator on PORT 5986 TO 10.10.10.5
<10.10.10.5> WINRM CONNECT: transport=ssl endpoint=https://10.10.10:5986/wsman
<10.10.10.5> WINRM OPEN SHELL: 5001549B-C9A9-41FF-B9A3-8D19155EE123
EXEC (via pipeline wrapper)
<10.10.10.5> WINRM EXEC 'PowerShell' ['-NoProfile', '-NonInteractive', '-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', '-']
<10.10.10.5> WINRM RESULT u'<Response code 1, out "{"changed":false,"an", err "\r\n">'
<10.10.10.5> WINRM CLOSE SHELL: 5001549B-C9A9-41FF-B9A3-8D19155EE123
```

Is there a way I can debug this?

Comment: -ComputerName is looking for a string. Try Enter-PSSession -ComputerName '10.10.10.5' -Credential administrator

Answer (score 0):

-ComputerName is looking for a string.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName '10.10.10.5' -Credential administrator
```

'10.10.10.5' will now have a TypeName of System.String

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Error is the same ofter using 'string'.

Answer (score 0):

Does the target machine have PowerShell remoting setup correctly? Depending on the target machine you may need to set that up manually.

See: [Enabling Remoting Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx)

From that article...

1. Start Windows PowerShell as an administrator by right-clicking the Windows PowerShell shortcut and selecting Run As Administrator.
2. The WinRM service is confi gured for manual startup by default. You must change the startup type to Automatic and start the service on each computer you want to work with. At the PowerShell prompt, you can verify that the WinRM service is running using the following command: 
   get-service winrm
   The value of the Status property in the output should be “Running”.
3. To configure Windows PowerShell for remoting, type the following command: 
   Enable-PSRemoting –force

Comment: Yes it has enabled. I can do Enter-PSSession from windows desktops to this serrver, just not from Linux/docker powershell to the same server, and as I understand ansible also uses the same type of connection (winrm).